# Скрыть ссылки с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Надо с двух ссылок:

1.

```
/user/info/anketa.php?id=1
```

Сделать

```
/user/ник
```

2.

```
/user/search.php?search=какой-то текст
```

сделать

```
/user/search/какой-то текст
```

Comment: @No0k, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

А где здесь ник? `/user/info/anketa.php?id=1`. По второму как-то так:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/search.php?search=(.*)$ /user/search/$1 [R]
```

Это будет переадресация с указанной тобой ссылки на указанный формат. Но обычно делают наоборот - с ЧПУ на ссылку с параметрами. И не редирект, а скрытую подстановку.